# Deployment according to environment and user privileges through TFS CI

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration

I have trying to implement CI for my desktop .NET application. But I am stuck at how to implement some stuff.

According to the requirements, I need to implement a filter while releasing the build according to user privileges and also filter the funtionalities that need not be installed on production.

I used to do this manually using a `manifest.xml` but now it seems a bit tidious to implement the same through TFS without using the Manifest.

My manifest looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Manifest UpdaterVersion="3.33.7.717">
  <f t="DLL" v="0.86.5.0" p="Module1.dll" />
  <f t="DLL" v="1.26.2.123" d="true" x="true" p="File\Module2.dll" />
```

In this example "d" is for dll not be installed on production and "x" is for power user only.

Can anyone help me find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you just want restrict user to create the release or Manage deployments ? In TFS there are permission setting could achieve this. You could check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbsprelease-object-level-vsts-tfs-2017? As for the judge something not be installed on production,did you want a filter based on the artifacts.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Thanks for your response! 
Not related to the TFS permissions. As you said in the last sentence, I want to be able to filter based on the artifacts.
The user permissions are determined when the user tries to login into the application after it is installed in the machine. So according to the user privileges, files would be downloaded from the server.